# How to find sequence in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

could You explain me how to find sequences in text file in Python3?

For example i have text file:

```
1
2
3
3
3
1
2
2
4
```

And now, for example i want to count how many sequences of '3' are in this file (in this example there is one sequence 3,3,3).

Thank You

Comment: Did you try anything? Why would we do your homework?

Comment: I just tried to find any function to do this, but i did not find anything useful thats why i am asking here.

Comment: Well, this is kind of specific problem, so you gotta write it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html)

test.txt:

```
1
2
3
3
3
4
4
5
6
7
8
8
8
8
9
```

im assuming there could be only one appearance of a certain sequences

```
from collections import Counter  

with open('test.txt' ,'r') as f:
    sequences = Counter(f.read().replace("\n", ""))


for seq, count  in sequences.items():
    if count > 1:
        print('number {} appears {} times'.format(seq, count))
```

output:

```
number 4 appears 2 times
number 3 appears 3 times
number 8 appears 4 times
```

Comment: OP needs to count the number of sequences, so the answer should be 1. Also, you shouldn't make a list out of the file for this task.

Comment: @khajvah you are correct, answer fixed

Comment: there is **the only** sequence of `3`s in the file. The answer should be one for `3`, not three. @Mateusz: Use `itertools.groupby()` to find sequences: [`Counter(k for k, _ in groupby(map(str.strip, file)))`](http://ideone.com/2dgTbA)